# Javascript replace() and $1 issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a script that searches for a pattern in text and wrap a tag around the string it finds.

```
$(".shop_attributes td").each(function () {
    $(this).html(function(i, html) {
        return html.replace(/E[0-9]{3,4}/g, "<strong>$1</strong>");
    });
});
```

this is the code i use and it does find what i'm looking but what it actually does is produce a  tag with $1 inside. What i expect it to do is to put the string it found into strong tags.  What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to capture the match, before you can use it. Use parentheses:

```
$(".shop_attributes td").each(function () {
    $(this).html(function(i, html) {
        return html.replace(/(E[0-9]{3,4})/g, "<strong>$1</strong>");
    });
});
```

[Ridiculously over-simplified JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/m2hWR/).

Comment: Thanks a ton, I've spent good 3 hours banging my head against keyboard.

Comment: Yeah, it took me a while, too, when I was learning regular expressions. It took me even longer to realise that it *really is*, despite what people say, a black and difficult magic...

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use `$&`, which stands for the whole match (also `$0` in other flavors):

```
html.replace(/E[0-9]{3,4}/g, "<strong>$&</strong>");
```

I'd also recommend the [jQuery Highlight Plugin](http://bartaz.github.com/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html) - You might be able to adapt it to use a regex, the code is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the group you want to capture in brackets:

```
/(E[0-9]{3,4})/g
```